# Подвал сайта улетает вверх

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Использую данный способ прибития подвала вниз. Но при подключении файла, уходит вверх. Для ознакомления с ситуацией есть сайт: http://l37-195-222-8.novotelecom.ru/remdvig.html

```css
.content{
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}

.footer {
  height: 80px;
  background: #1D1E22;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще все проблемы из-за `min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);` Но если он действительно нужен, то можно поиграться с `flex` и автоматическим `margin` для `footer`:

```
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.footer {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```